# Not able to read stream using Java Graph SDK for an attachment

Tags: java, outlook, sdk, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Graph Explorer suggests below code snippet in Java to read the stream of Email attachment.

```
Stream stream = graphClient.me().messages(<message_id>).attachments(<attachment_id>).content()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

But Java Graph SDK (1.9.0 I use) is not having `.content()` method. Do I need to do custom request to endpoint using below URI or is there any alternative method Java SDK support to achieve this?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<message_id>/attachments/<attachment_id>/$value
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the above the $value method.

Comment: You can try getting the attachment object at /attachments/attachment_id endpoint and get the contentBytes property value and decode it. Please go through this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971537/how-to-retrieve-office-365-mail-file-like-image-text-file-etc-attachment-using)

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity  I have gone with custom request for now. Will give it a try soon with the approach you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Maneesh, moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting the attachment object at `/attachments/attachment_id` endpoint and get the contentBytes property value and decode it. Please go through this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971537/how-to-retrieve-office-365-mail-file-like-image-text-file-etc-attachment-using) for code referrence.